# Local Notifications/Alarms on iOS similar to AlarmManager from Android

Tags: xamarin.ios, notifications

I am new to iOS app and I would really appreciate your help.

I want to implement Notifications/Alarms that will run foreground and/or background for my iOS App. 
I want to set multiple alarms and being appeared let's say every day.

I couldn't be able to find a proper solution, but I found the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows 
Do you think that that will work in my case? Any comments will be helpful.
How can I avoid being rejecting from the Apple store?

Thanks

Comment: Yes,you can add local notification in the method DidEnterBackground and WillEnterForeground in AppDelegate.cs.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how to use these two functions. Could you please provide with an example of how to generate a schedule a notification what will work for both foreground and background?

Comment: Actually helped me the following link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications which descrices how to generate local notifications and schedule them.